# installing scala test libraryDependencies error

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, scalatest

when I'm installing scala test dependencies with Intellij Idea in my project  I receive the following error

```
libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "2.2.6" % "test"
```

Error:Error while importing SBT project:
...

```
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scalatest/scalatest_2.12/2.2.6/scalatest_2.12-2.2.6.pom
[info] Resolving org.scala-lang#scala-compiler;2.12.2 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-lang#scala-reflect;2.12.2 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-lang.modules#scala-xml_2.12;1.0.6 ...
[info] Resolving jline#jline;2.14.3 ...
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: org.scalatest#scalatest_2.12;2.2.6: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]
[warn]  Note: Unresolved dependencies path:
[warn]      org.scalatest:scalatest_2.12:2.2.6 (/Users/user/IdeaProjects/Example/build.sbt#L8-9)
[warn]        +- default:example_2.12:1.0
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run 'last *:ssExtractProject' for the full output.
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run 'last :update' for the full output.
[error] (:ssExtractProject) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.scalatest#scalatest_2.12;2.2.6: not found
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.scalatest#scalatest_2.12;2.2.6: not found
[error] Total time: 6 s, completed May 14, 2017 8:48:04 PM
```

See complete log in file:/Users/user/Library/Logs/IdeaIC2017.1/sbt.last.log

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

Version 2.2.6 is incompatible with Scala 2.12, you should use the [latest available version](http://www.scalatest.org/install) (3.0.1).

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem , it is due to using older unsupported version.
you should use newer version of ScalaTest:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.0.4" % "test"
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what you want:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "2.2.6" % Test
```

Comment: Also, as @nikita-gousak mentioned, you should be using the latest version of scalatest